Как в C++ преобразовать объект базового класса в наследуемый?
Допустим, я имею базовый класс и несколько наследуемых от него (Первое выделение на рисунке). Также у меня есть массив указателей на базовый класс, содержащий наследуемые от него классы (Второе выделение на рисунке).

Я знаю, под каким индексом находится нужный мне элемент и его тип, и хочу получить/назначить значение переменной характерной для этого класса. В C# с этим бы не было проблем, но тут я упираюсь в то, что не знаю, как преобразовать полученный объект базового класса в наследуемый.
(Извиняюсь, если плохо объяснил свою проблему. Ещё один краткий пример: есть объект предмета, от него наследуется объект оружия и объект еды с дополнительными параметрами. В инвентаре(массиве указателей на предмет) хранятся меч и яблоко. Как мне получить параметры меча, если я знаю, что выбранной ячейке инвентаря меч?)

Вместо рисунков лучше показывать код. (Или в крайнем случае UML - стандартизованные схемы, с понятными другим людям обозначениями.)

Можно сделать dynamic_cast или static_cast в указатель (или ссылку) на дочерний класс. Но это обычно редко бывает нужно, уверены что вам недостаточно вызывать виртуальные функции на указателях на родителей?

Когда необходимо делать такое, то у вас ошибка в архитектуре приложения... Никогда не должно требоваться делать обратное преобразование, кроме редких случаев, который таковым не является. А для определения типа предмета в инвентаре, обычно делается геттер на тип предмета.
